# Errors due to androidx drawerlayout

Tags: java, android

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cn/com.example.cn.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
android:id="@+id/drawable_layout"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="match_parent"  
android:paddingLeft="10dp"  
android:paddingBottom="5dp"  
tools:context="com.example.cn.MainActivity"  
android:paddingStart="10dp"  
tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">
```

app

'''

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.cn"
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  
//noinspection GradleCompatible  
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'  
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'  
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'  
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'  
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'  
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'  
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'  
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.1'  
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'  
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'  
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'  
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'  
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'  
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'  
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-   
alpha01'  
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha02'    
}
```

'''

Comment: please do help.

Comment: Are you using correct `dependencies`? Is your project set to use `androidx`?

Comment: I will upload the dependencies

Comment: please check ..

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

Error is obvious. You are using `Android Support Libraries` in `dependencies` but in `layout` you are trying to use `androidx`.

For example:

**Android Support Libray:** `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`

**AndroidX:** `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0`

So you have one of the two options either continue using `Android Support Libraries` which means you need to rename `DrawerLayout` to `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` or to upgrade project to `AndroidX`.

To make upgrade you can do that from Android Studio by going on `Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX`.

If you decide to use this way, follow suggestions provided by Android Studio it will `zip` your project and than make upgrade. That means you can always return to your project before `AndroidX` upgrade.

> Also there is possibility that not all things will work after upgrade
>   and maybe manually adjustment will be needed.

Or manually: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added the dependency.

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Then use the tag android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.

Comment: Were should I put this tag in

Comment: if you use `com.android.support` then you should **not** be using `androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout` since that's the DrawerLayout from AndroidX. Note: the support library is outdated. Many libraries are moving away from it as well. Use AndroidX

Comment: I did d merging to androidx

Answer (score 0):

I think You have defined the v4 version of drawer layout in your java class or kotlin class.
thats why its giving you error